# Two way data binding on Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, components, vue-component

I am using vue js and laravel for my project. I am facing one issue that is 2 way data binding. Let me explain scenario. Please check screenshot. https://prnt.sc/n5qfi5

In this screenshot there are 2 section upper and lower. I have created 2 component **uppercomponent** and **lowercomponent**. When user type on upper component text input 1 then onchange event it will reflect on lower component text input 1, Now on lower component there are lots of lines on screenshot there are showing 4 lines, User can add multiple lines. So if user will add new line then we will copy last line input fields data and populate on new line input fields and then user can change the values for input.

If user add 6 lines on lower component and click on 2nd line then we will fetch all input fields data from 2nd line lower component and populate on upper component input fields.

Please check my code and help me.

**UPPERCOMPONENT**

```
**<template>
    <div class="sign-lines column">
        <ul>
            <input type=hidden name='maxsign' id="maxsign" :value="maxsign" >
            <input type=hidden name='currentsign' id="currentsign" :value="currentsign" >
            <li v-for="index in localInputs" :key="index">
                <div class="radio-btn">
                    <small>{{ $t('Line') }}{{index}}</small>
                    <label class="controls control--radio">                        
                        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-fld">
                    <div class="field">
                        <p class="control has-icons-right">
                            <input class="input" :id="'rows'+index" type="text" :value="index == '1' ? 'Text 1' : ''" v-on:keyup="RowChanged(index,$event.target.value);"  v-on:blur="OnFocusRow(index,$event.target.value);" @focus="OnFocusRow(index,$event.target.value);" :maxlength="finalData.maxTextLimit" />
                            <span class="icon is-small is-right"> {{defaultFontSize}}</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input-btn">
                    <input type="hidden" name="fontsize1" value="5">
                    <a class="button is-danger"  @click="DecrRow(index);"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="button is-success" @click="IncrRow(index);"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a class="button is-danger"  @click="removeRow(index);" :class="index > '4' ? 'removeRow' : 'hideRemoveRow'">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>                
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p v-show="seen" class="show-m" @click="addMore()">{{ $t('showMoreRows') }}</p>
    </div> 
</template>    
<script> 
import Button from '~/components/Button';
import { EventBus } from '../eventbus/event-bus.js';
export default {
    name: 'middle-four-section',    
    components : {
        Button
    },
    props: ['finalData'],
    data(){
        return {
            currentsign:0,
            maxsign:0,
            localInputs:4,
            seen:true,
            defaultFontSize : 5,
            hideSymbol:false,
            defaultLineNumber:1, 
            activeInputForSymbol:1,
            activeInputValueForSymbol:''
        }
    }, 
    methods:{
        OnRowsChanged(){

        },
        RowChanged(index,value){ 
            var inputData = {};
            inputData.index         = index;
            inputData.value         = value;
            inputData.lineNumber    = this.defaultLineNumber;
            this.activeInputForSymbol = index;
            this.activeInputValueForSymbol = value;
            EventBus.$emit('getInputTypeData',inputData);
        },
        OnFocusRow(index,value){
            var inputData = {};
            inputData.index         = index;
            inputData.value         = value;
            inputData.lineNumber    = this.defaultLineNumber;
            this.activeInputForSymbol = index;
            this.activeInputValueForSymbol = value;
            EventBus.$emit('getInputTypeData',inputData);
        },
        DecrRow(index){
            var minVal = 3;
            var maxVal = 50;
        },
        IncrRow(index){
        },
        addMore(clicked){ 
            if(this.localInputs < 6){
                this.localInputs +=1;
            }  
            if(this.localInputs == 6){
                this.seen = false;
            }
        },
        removeRow(){
            if(this.localInputs > 4){
                this.localInputs -=1;
                this.seen = true;
            }
        },
        OnClickSymbol(){
            this.hideSymbol = true;
        },
        closeSymbolPopUp(){
            this.hideSymbol = false;
        },
        OnInsertSymbol(activeInput,symbol){
            this.activeInputValueForSymbol = this.activeInputValueForSymbol+symbol;
            console.log('this.activeInputValueForSymbol --------------- ',this.activeInputValueForSymbol);
            //this.hideSymbol = false;
        }
    },
    created(){
        EventBus.$on('getLineIndex',lineInputData => {
            this.defaultLineNumber = lineInputData.lineNumber;
            console.log('getLineIndex',lineInputData);
            //alert(lineInputData);
        });
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>  
.hideRemoveRow{display: none;}
#symboldiv{position: absolute; background-color: yellow; border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; height: 200px;z-index: 111;}
</style>**
```

**LOWERCOMPONENT**

```
<template> 
    <div class="sign-btm signlist" id="signlist"> 
        <div class="columns" v-for="index in inputs" :name="'signlistrow'+index" @click="getLineIndex(index)" :class="{clicked:clickedDiv == index}">
            <div class="column is-0">
                <div class="tb-sr">
                    <p>{{ $t('ID') }}</p>
                    <div class="input" :id="'signIndexBg_'+index"><span :id="'signIndexTxt_'+index">{{index}}</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="tb-sr">
                    <p>{{ $t('Line1') }}</p>
                    <input type="input" class="input" :id="'string1R'+index" v-on:keyup="OnListChange(1,$event.target.value);" autocomplete="off" value="Text 1" maxlength="250" size="36" v-model="finalData.text_1_[index]">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="tb-sr">
                    <p>{{ $t('Line2') }}</p>
                    <input type="input" class="input" :id="'string2R'+index" v-on:keyup="OnListChange(2,$event.target.value);" autocomplete="off" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);" maxlength="250" size="36" v-model="finalData.text_2_[index]">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="tb-sr">
                    <p>{{ $t('Line3') }}</p>
                    <input type="input" class="input" :id="'string3R'+index" v-on:keyup="OnListChange(3,$event.target.value);" autocomplete="off" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);" maxlength="250" size="36" v-model="finalData.text_3_[index]">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="tb-sr">
                    <p>{{ $t('Line4') }}</p>
                    <input type="input" class="input" :id="'string4R'+index" v-on:keyup="OnListChange(4,$event.target.value);" autocomplete="off" style="background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);" maxlength="250" size="36" v-model="finalData.text_4_[index]">
                    <input type="hidden" :id="'string5R'+index" v-on:keyup="OnListChange(5,$event.target.value);" v-model="finalData.text_5_[index]">
                    <input type="hidden" :id="'string6R'+index" v-on:keyup="OnListChange(6,$event.target.value);" v-model="finalData.text_6_[index]">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End inputs add more div -->
        <div class="input-btn">
            <a class="button is-danger" @click="DeleteSign(1)"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="button is-success" @click="AddSign();setLocalSorage();"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div> 
    </div>    
</template>

<script> 
import { EventBus } from '../eventbus/event-bus.js';

export default {
    name: 'lower-full-section',    
    props: ['finalData'],
    data(){
        return {
            inputs : 1,
            clickedDiv:1,
            defaultLines:1,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        OnListChange(inputTypeIndex,valueofInput){
            var inputData = {};
            inputData.index         = inputTypeIndex;
            inputData.value         = valueofInput;
            inputData.lineNumber    = this.clickedDiv; 
            EventBus.$emit('getLineIndex',inputData);
        },
        AddSign(){
          this.inputs +=1;   
        },
        DeleteSign(){
            if(this.inputs > 1){
                this.inputs -=1; 
            } else {
                alert('You can not delete all rows.');
            }
        },
        setLocalSorage(){

        },
        getLineIndex(index){
            this.clickedDiv = index;
        }
    },
    created(){
        EventBus.$on('getInputTypeData', lineInputData => {
            console.log('lineInputData',lineInputData);
        });
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.clicked{background: #FFFACD;}
</style>
```

Comment: Did you explain the way it should work, or the way it works, and there is an issue with that? Can you explain what the main issue is?

Comment: @niklaz, I will work like i have explained. I have pass data from one component to other component with the help of Emit and On event but unable to set on input fields  values becasue at the end when user click on submit button i need all data on submit page.

Comment: Ok, can you point out the issue, since it is very thorough explanation, and issue is not obvious. Thanks :)

Comment: @niklaz, Can we do chat on stackoverflow chat option

Comment: @niklaz, Please join this room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191009/vue-js-room-for-chat